# Accurate measurement of object sizes

Tags: java, memory, jvm

The code at the bottom of this question is a bit long but basically creates a few objects and determines their size in memory. I execute the code with the following JVM parameters (TLAB to avoid chunk memory allocation and supposedly get accurate memory usage figures):

```
-server -Xms2000m -Xmx2000m -verbose:gc -XX:-UseTLAB
```

I run the code on a 64 bit Hotspot JVM and get the following output:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   Object: 16 bytes
>
> Object with 1 int: 16 bytes
>   Object with 2 ints: 24 bytes
>   Object with 3 ints: 24 bytes
>
> Object with 1 long: 24 bytes
>   Object with 2 longs: 32 bytes
>   Object with 3 longs: 40 bytes
>
> Object with 1 reference: 16 bytes
>   Object with 2 references: 24 bytes
>   Object with 3 references: 24 bytes

I conclude that:

- an object takes 12 bytes, aligned to 16 bytes.
- an int takes 4 bytes (1 object with one int is 12 + 4 = still 16 bytes, with 2 ints: 12 + 8 = 20 aligned to 24 bytes)
- a long takes 8 bytes (1 object with one long is 12 + 8 = 20 bytes, aligned to 24 bytes)

**But I struggle to understand why references don't use as much space as `long`s.**

Since references are 8 bytes on a 64-bit JVM, the obvious conclusion is that the measurement methodology has a flaw*.
Can you explain what is going on and what can be done to fix it?

<sub>*Notes:</sub>
<sub>- no GC runs during the measurement.</sub>
<sub>- using the Netbeans profiler yields similar results.</sub>

```
public class TestMemoryReference {

    private static final int SIZE = 100_000;
    private static Runnable r;
    private static Object o = new Object();
    private static Object o1 = new Object();
    private static Object o2 = new Object();
    private static Object o3 = new Object();

    public static class ObjectWith1Int  { int i; }
    public static class ObjectWith2Ints { int i, j; }
    public static class ObjectWith3Ints { int i, j, k; }
    public static class ObjectWith1Long  { long i; }
    public static class ObjectWith2Longs { long i, j; }
    public static class ObjectWith3Longs { long i, j, k; }
    public static class ObjectWith1Object  { Object o = o1; }
    public static class ObjectWith2Objects { Object o = o1; Object p = o2; }
    public static class ObjectWith3Objects { Object o = o1; Object p = o2; Object q = o3; }

    private static void test(Runnable r, String name, int numberOfObjects) {
        long mem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        r.run();
        System.out.println(name + ":" + (mem - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / numberOfObjects + " bytes  ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name") + "  ");

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new Object(); } };
        test(r, "Object", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith1Int(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 1 int", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith2Ints(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 2 ints", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith3Ints(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 3 ints", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith1Long(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 1 long", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith2Longs(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 2 longs", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith3Longs(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 3 longs", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith1Object(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 1 reference", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith2Objects(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 2 references", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new ObjectWith3Objects(); } };
        test(r, "Object with 3 references", SIZE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since references are 8 bytes on a 64-bit JVM

This is your potentially-flawed assumption.

HotSpot is able to use ["compressed oops"](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) to use 32-bit values for references in *some* places of the JVM (emphasis mine):

> Which oops are compressed?
>
> In an ILP32-mode JVM, or if the UseCompressedOops flag is turned off in LP64 mode, all oops are the native machine word size.
>
> If UseCompressedOops is true, the following oops in the heap will be compressed:
>
> - the klass field of every object
> - **every oop instance field**
> - every element of an oop array (objArray)

I *suspect* this is what's going on in your case.

Test it by using

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```

or

```
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

On my machine, by default I get the same results as you, but with `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` I see:

```
Object:16 bytes
Object with 1 int:24 bytes
Object with 2 ints:24 bytes
Object with 3 ints:32 bytes
Object with 1 long:24 bytes
Object with 2 longs:32 bytes
Object with 3 longs:40 bytes
Object with 1 reference:24 bytes
Object with 2 references:32 bytes
Object with 3 references:40 bytes
```

... which is probably closer to what you were expecting :)

Comment: Aargh - I thought the `UseCompressedOops` defaulted to false - it turns out it is enabled by default. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Java Object's size is known when the class is defined.

Memory usage of Java objects: general http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

Comment: Instrumentation is sometimes less precise than a direct measurement. And the link does not address 64 bit jvms with the compressed pointers option.